# Encyclopedia that works offline (alternative to Encarta)

Tags: windows-7, offline, knowledge-base, children

Encarta was abandoned in 2009 because everyone uses Wikipedia. But I need a software similar to Encarta or Britannica.

I'm installing some software on a Windows 7 laptop that belongs to a 10 years old girl. Her parents don't have Internet yet. They asked me to install some encyclopedia for her that would work offline until they get Internet working.

My requirements are:

1. Free encyclopedia that works on Windows 7 32 bit, not necessarily open source.
2. It has to work offline and updates itself when connected to the Internet.
3. Maintained and updated.
4. No adult content, suitable for kids.
5. Big plus if it has features for kids. If I remember correctly, Encarta had a version for kids and there was a software that taught maths for kids too.
6. Big plus if it supports many languages, the kid is a native Arabic speaker, she's taught English and French at school.

Comment: Whats wrong with Britannica?

Comment: @Mr.Alien as far as I know, there's no britanica software that would work offline anymore, I think it's gone too, the website remains

Comment: Britannica can work off-line http://store.britannica.com/collections/software/products/04211280jcas (Internet recommended though) but isn't free anyway. ($10, still cheaper than paper version…)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Britannica, I used to have it, the DVD says it's 2012, is it still updated or is 2012 the newest version available?

Comment: I'd say newest version available.

Comment: it's decades since the last time I've heard of Encarta :) Anyway there are numerous ways to use wikipedia, although it's a bit bulky in terms of space

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Kiwix](http://www.kiwix.org/wiki/Main_Page):

- free and open source
- Windows, OSX, Android, Linux and most other OSes
- offline reader for web content. It's software intended to make Wikipedia available without using the internet.
- No kid filters though AFAIK, and no auto-update last time I tried

[image]

FYI: [Wikipedia:Database download](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download).

Comment: Use the 2.5GB "for-schools" version instead of the 55GB full version, if it is for your 10yo. http://download.kiwix.org/zim/wikipedia_en_for-schools.zim

Comment: The "Simple English" version is another option, at 1GB: http://download.kiwix.org/zim/wikipedia_en_simple_all.zim

Comment: Regarding the 6th requirement: Yes, many other languages are available too.

Comment: i too have been looking for an offline encyclopedia, i remember a full set usually requires a single large book case. ah ye good olden days